# coming soon (launching soon) page for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an already working website and I need a coming soon page for everyone but the admin users. So I would like to have a way for admins to authenticate when they go to /login and use the website if they provide the right credentials and if not, just display the coming soon page.

Thanks,
Cezar

Answer (score 3):

You can apply simple authentication filter everywhere except the login page

```
unless admin?
   redirect_to comming_soon_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [launching soon](http://vinsol.com/blog/2009/07/14/launching-soon/) plugin which includes a bunch of features for mailing interested users in conjunction with whatever solution you come up with (I don't see anything about restricting access to the remainder of the site though).